# Camera for Windows Hello on Windows IOT Core for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I'm looking for a camera (module) that is suitable for Windows Hello (Microsoft's biometric facial recognition) on Windows IOT Core which runs on a Raspberry Pi.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I unfortunately have no idea if Hello is supported by IoT Core. Information seems to be somewhat lacking on it.

Answer (score 1):

The top three search results for “windows hello webcam requirements” claim that you need a special infrared, 3D camera:

> If Windows Hello doesn’t work, chances are your hardware isn’t compatible. That means your system lacks iris scanning, fingerprint scanning, or a near-infrared 3D camera.

<sup>[Source](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-windows-hello/)</sup>

> A regular webcam will not work with Windows Hello. Windows 10 features Windows Hello, which provides new ways to authentication using biometrics including facial recognition.  Since this is essentially 3-d detection,  a camera with a specialized illuminated infrared camera is required.

<sup>[Source](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/q-what-required-use-windows-hello-facial-recognition-logon-windows-10)</sup>

> No, common cameras like Logitech C920 does not meet requirement.
>
> Windows Hello face authentication utilizes a camera specially configured for near infrared (IR) imaging to authenticate and unlock Windows devices as well as unlock your Microsoft Passport. Just as you mentioned, “you must have devices with integrated special infrared (IR) sensors and software”.

<sup>[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b221801-472d-4b5e-a821-22910e4d1c51/camera-requirements-for-windows-hello-facial-recognition?forum=win10itprosecurity)</sup>

Searching specifically for such camera module for Raspberry Pi, or even a simple 3D camera, gives nothing. Nor could I find the list of compatible camera devices anyway—there are just lots of pages from three years ago, promising such a list and giving a dead link.

What I found, however, are the projects made by other persons who, as you, wanted to play with Windows Hello, and they all used an external USB camera instead of a Raspberry Pi camera module.

[Here's such example](https://www.hackster.io/windows-iot/windows-iot-facial-recognition-door-e087ce) which relies on Microsoft Lifecam 3000.

Although I haven't a definitive proof, I think there is either no such camera module, or if there is, it is not very popular, and thus won't have enough support to work seamlessly with Windows Hello. If I were you, I'd buy one of the compatible USB cameras instead, even if it means (1) wasting an USB port, (2) losing the warranty as soon as you remove the electronics from the case, and (3) spending much more money then needed.